# TikZ set text above node to same distance as other text

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

consider the following code for a TikZ image:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}
\tikzset{%
    Block/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, draw, text width = 2.5cm, align = center, minimum height = 1.5cm}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1cm, thick]
        
        \node[Block] (KP) {process};
        
        \node[Block, below=of KP] (VA) {sales};
        
        \node[Block, below left=of VA] (EL) {delivery};
        
        \node[Block, below right=of VA] (UeL) {examination};
        
        \draw[-latex'] (KP) -- (VA);
        
        \coordinate[below=0.25cm of VA] (Verbindung);
        
        \draw (VA) -- (Verbindung);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Verbindung) -| (EL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Verbindung) -| (UeL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (EL) -- (UeL) node [midway, above] {manual};
        
        \coordinate[below=3cm of VA] (Verbindung2);
        
        \draw[dashed, -latex'] (EL) |- (Verbindung2) -| (UeL);
        
        \node[above=0.1cm of Verbindung2] (digital) {digital};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

How can I set the word "digital" the same distance above the dashed arrow as the  word "manual" is above its respective arrow, as even setting the value to 0cm doesn't produce the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not concerned about the issue of the descender in the letter `g`, you can place the `digital` using:

```
\node[below=3cm of VA, above] (digital) {digital};
```

[image]

If the descender is an issue you can use

```
\draw[-latex'] (EL) -- (UeL) node [midway, above] {manual\vphantom{g}};
```

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}
\tikzset{%
    Block/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, draw, text width = 2.5cm, align = center, minimum height = 1.5cm}}

\pagecolor{white}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1cm, thick]
        
        \node[Block] (KP) {process};
        
        \node[Block, below=of KP] (VA) {sales};
        
        \node[Block, below left=of VA] (EL) {delivery};
        
        \node[Block, below right=of VA] (UeL) {examination};
        
        \draw[-latex'] (KP) -- (VA);
        
        \coordinate[below=0.25cm of VA] (Verbindung);
        
        \draw (VA) -- (Verbindung);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Verbindung) -| (EL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (Verbindung) -| (UeL);
        
        \draw[-latex'] (EL) -- (UeL) node [midway, above] {manual};
        
        \coordinate[below=3cm of VA] (Verbindung2);
        
        \draw[dashed, -latex'] (EL) |- (Verbindung2) -| (UeL);
        
        \node[below=3cm of VA, above] (digital) {digital};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, both lines of code helped me!